# How to get the click event on sIFR embedded tag in IE?

Tags: javascript, flash, internet-explorer, sifr

I have implemented [Scalable Inman Flash Replacement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalable_Inman_Flash_Replacement) (sIFR) to convert text. The issue is, I'm unable to do `onClick` event over the iSFR embed tags.

```
$(function() {
    $("embed").click(function(){
        alert('clicked over embed');
    });
});
```

This works in Firefox but not in Internet Explorer.
Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 2):

Flash movies tend to eat these events.

sIFR 3 lets you specify an `onRelease` callback handler in the `sIFR.replace()` arguments, which is called when the Flash movie is clicked on.

Answer (score 1):

It might also be worth checking out cufón at http://cufon.shoqolate.com/generate/